# How php call stack works with return and echo

Tags: php

I'm not sure how php execute this decorator design pattern example.
the problem is when I use return in the operation function it gets called from down to up and when using echo in the operation function it gets called from up to down like the code below.
I don't understand how this behavior works.

**echo behavior**

```
<?php 
 
 interface IBaseInterface {
     public function operation();
    }
    
    class BaseComponent implements IBaseInterface{
        public function operation(){
            echo "baseComponent";
        }
    }
    
    class baseDecorator implements IBaseInterface {
    protected  $component;
    
    public function __construct(IBaseInterface $component){
        $this->component = $component;
    }
    
    public function operation(){
        echo $this->component->operation();
    }
    
}

class concreteDecoratorA extends baseDecorator {
    public function operation(){
        echo "ConcreteDecoratorA(". parent::operation() . ")";  
    }
}

class concreteDecoratorB extends baseDecorator {
    public function operation(){
        
        echo "ConcreteDecoratorB(". parent::operation() . ")";  
    }
}


$simple  = new BaseComponent();

$decorator1 = new concreteDecoratorA($simple);
$decorator2 = new concreteDecoratorB($decorator1);

$decorator2->operation();

?>
```

**output**

```
baseComponentConcreteDecoratorA()ConcreteDecoratorB()
```

** return behavior**

```
<?php 
 
 interface IBaseInterface {
     public function operation();
    }
    
    class BaseComponent implements IBaseInterface{
        public function operation(){
            return "baseComponent";
        }
    }
    
    class baseDecorator implements IBaseInterface {
    protected  $component;
    
    public function __construct(IBaseInterface $component){
        $this->component = $component;
    }
    
    public function operation(){
        return $this->component->operation();
    }
    
}

class concreteDecoratorA extends baseDecorator {
    public function operation(){
        return "ConcreteDecoratorA(". parent::operation() . ")";  
    }
}

class concreteDecoratorB extends baseDecorator {
    public function operation(){
        
        return "ConcreteDecoratorB(". parent::operation() . ")";  
    }
}


$simple  = new BaseComponent();

$decorator1 = new concreteDecoratorA($simple);
$decorator2 = new concreteDecoratorB($decorator1);

echo $decorator2->operation();

?>
```

**output**

```
ConcreteDecoratorB(ConcreteDecoratorA(baseComponent))
```

Comment: `echo` outputs the data straight away. A `return` doesn't output anything, it just returns the value to the caller to do with what it wants. In your `return`-examples, you return the string and put it inside another string, which you then echo. It's the same as: `echo 'foo'; echo 'bar';` vs `$foo = 'foo'; echo 'bar' . $foo;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call stack doesn't change.  But *what the methods do* changes.  When you `echo` something, it outputs *immediately*.  When you `return` something, the calling code shown outputs the value *later*.

Consider the semantics of this statement:

```
echo "ConcreteDecoratorB(". parent::operation() . ")";
```

It can be interpreted as:

1. Do `parent::operation()` first, whatever it does.
2. Whatever `parent::operation()` *returned*, concatenate it to this string.
3. Output this string.

So if `parent::operation()` *outputs a string* but *returns nothing* then the result will be whatever `parent::operation()` outputs is printed to the screen, then this string literal is printed to the screen.

Alternatively, consider the semantics of this:

```
return "ConcreteDecoratorB(". parent::operation() . ")";
```

Which is:

1. Do `parent::operation()` first, whatever it does.
2. Whatever `parent::operation()` *returned*, concatenate it to this string.
3. Return this string.

In thie case, Step 3 changed, *but* your implementation of `parent::operation()` is also different in that example.  So if `parent::operation()` *returns a string* then so far nothing has been outputted.  That *returned string* is concatenated into this string, and the whole combined string is returned.

Calling code then outputs it at the very end:

```
echo $decorator2->operation();
```

Ultimately, the difference is between *printing a string now and returning nothing* vs. *returning a string to be combined with other strings and printed later*.

The call stack is the same either way.  You're just doing two logically different things in your operations.

Comment: Absolutely right, I figure out that my logic was slightly wrong